# how to restrict the app to rebuild the widget tree when orientation changed to landscape?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a screen1, screen2, screen3 and screen4. So basically when i use the youtube player package in flutter and when i set the orientation to landscape then the video is playing on the screen4 in lanscape mode but after sometimes screen1 rendered on the screen4 without calling the screen1. I guess when orientation changed then the widget tree is rebuidling so how to force this process in flutter.

code is given below for scrren4 so basically i call this screen from screen3.

```html
class _FullScreenVideoScreen extends State<FullScreenVideoScreen> {
  final Key myKey = UniqueKey();
  late BuildContext _parentContext;

  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(DeviceOrientation.values);
    super.dispose();
  }

  // @override
  // void didChangeDependencies() {
  //   super.didChangeDependencies();
  //   print("dididididididiidididiididid");
  //   // Trigger a rebuild when the orientation changes
  //   WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  //     SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  //       DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  //       DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  //     ]);
  //   });
  // }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _parentContext = context;

          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: YoutubePlayer(
                  controller: YoutubePlayerController(
                    initialVideoId: widget.videoId,
                    flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
                      mute: false,
                      autoPlay: true,
                      disableDragSeek: false,
                      loop: false,
                      isLive: false,
                      forceHD: false,
                      enableCaption: true,
                      showLiveFullscreenButton : false,
                    ),
                  ),
                  showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                  progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I try to understand your case problem, but still don't understand. Maybe you can explain more detail about what every screen are do?, how do you pass the variable from parent?, what is the code of parent page looks like?

Comment: can you tell me like how to force the widget tree rebuilding when the orientation changes to landscape mode?

Comment: You can do like this `Future.delayed(Durations.short2, () => setState(){});` on last line initState. I just confuse why do you want to rebuild again after the video playing in landscape?

Comment: I used this package (https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) to play the youtube video in the youtube player, but the thing is in screen3 i have a list of videos so when i click that i play the video in the screen3 itself but when i tap on the full screen button that is present at bottom, so orientation changes and the widget rebuilds, i don't why this screen1 is opening on the top of the player. so i want to force to rebuild the widget tree.

Comment: ohh i see, i think there is something a mistake on your screen1 code. Because your landscape code same like this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3l9o31AoeQ&ab_channel=HeyFlutter%E2%80%A4com) and there isn't any problem. Please show your code of screen 1,2,3,4 in here